# Rename a mysql table using textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am making a simple program to create a mysql table from vb.net and renaming it by user choice.

i got success in creating the table it is quite simple but how to rename a table from textbox tortured me a lot.

here's the code to create a table:

```
Try
 cnn.Open()
 Dim query As String
 query = "CREATE TABLE best.new (id INT NOT NULL,  name VARCHAR(45) NULL, date DATETIME NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (id));"

 cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, cnn)
 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 MessageBox.Show("table created")
 cnn.Close()
```

i tried to rename it using this code but no success....! achieved yet.

i tried few more but it gives error.

i want to rename it from the "id" given by the user:

```
Dim rename As String
 Rename = ("RENAME TABLE new To" TextBox1.Text)
 cmd = New MySqlCommand(Rename, cnn)
 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 MessageBox.Show("renamed")
 cnn.Close()
```

please help me to find it out

Comment: You should add a tag indicating what database you are using.  Also `but no success` tells us absolutely nothing about the issue.  Include actual error messages or real observations of behavior in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with code you posted.

First, you are missing `cnn.Open`. Second, you are missing a `+` in second line, it should be `Rename = ("RENAME TABLE new To" + TextBox1.Text)`.

Maybe it's just a typo and there's something different wrong with a code. So, post complete code and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty bad from a quality perspective.  In the future please try to include all essential details.  That would mean error messages and full/relevant source code.

As you are a newbie to SO I'll try my hand at psychic debugging.

It would appear that you have forgotten to open the database connection before trying to `ExecuteReader` the rename command.